# Python Poetry - "missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64')"

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I'm encountering an architecture-related error when running a Solders library in a Python Poetry virtual environment on my Intel-based MacBook. The error doesn't occur outside of Poetry, which leads me to believe it might be related to how Poetry handles architecture emulation.

Here's the error message I receive:

`missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64')`

Full error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(xxx/python3.10/site-packages/solders/solders.abi3.so, 0x0002): tried: 'xxx/python3.10/site-packages/solders/solders.abi3.so' (slice 1 extends beyond end of file, fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/solders/solders.abi3.so' (no such file), '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/xxx/lib/python3.10/site-packages/solders/solders.abi3.so' (slice 1 extends beyond end of file, fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'x86_64,arm64', need 'x86_64h' or 'x86_64'))
```

It seems like 'x86_64' isn't being correctly parsed or recognized by the function that verifies the architecture compatibility. Does anyone know how to solve this?